# how to add single wordpress post to multiple wp category with different different title

Tags: posts

my dear sir,

i have a website [www.allsarkariresult.in](http://www.allsarkariresult.in)

please check my site layout then try to solve my problem 
on this website i want  to publish a single post mostly three place but with different 2 title (to save from duplicate content problem)
 i have tried content box but it is not working 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this using no code. Title is property of post object, so it doesn't depend on the category the post belongs to. You can try to change the title using `the_title` filter.

```
function change_title_based_on_category( $title, $post_id = null ) {

    if ( in_category('some_category', $post_id ) ) {
        return 'My changed title';
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_title_based_on_category', 10, 2 );
```

Of course it's only a starting point. You can create some meta boxes to input additional titles in post editor and build some more advanced logic to change them according to category.